# C++ in Xcode - no member in namespace

Tags: c++, xcode

I have this code:

```
#ifndef LUA_CALLBACKS_H
#define LUA_CALLBACKS_H

extern "C"
{  
 #include "./lua_lib/lua.h"
 #include "./lua_lib/lualib.h"
 #include "./lua_lib/lauxlib.h"
}


#include "./LuaWrapper.h"

static int X(lua_State *L)
{
  LuaCpp::LuaWrapper::GetInstance();

  return 1;
}

#endif
```

In "LuaWrapper.h" I have:

```
#ifndef LUA_WRAPPER_H
#define LUA_WRAPPER_H

namespace LuaCpp
{   
    class LuaWrapper
    {
    public:
        static LuaWrapper * GetInstance() { return nullptr; }
    }
}

#endif
```

I have correctly included file with LuaWrapper. However, I have this error in XCode (LLVM 8.1)

> - No member name "LuaWrapper" in namespace LuaCpp

The same code compiles correctly in Visual Studio 2015. Note: The above code is "dummy", it wont do anything. But it dont compile nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

[Defining a class within a namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623903/defining-a-class-within-a-namespace)

This is a useful old post that said: you can declared a class to be the member of a namespace but you have to define the class outside of the namespace block.

ଘ(੭*ˊᵕˋ)੭* ̀ˋ Try define LuaWrapper's method GetInstance() outside of the namespace LuaWrapper?

```
    namespace LuaCpp { class LuaWrapper; }

    class LuaCpp::LuaWrapper {
    public:
        static LuaWrapper * GetInstance() { return nullptr; }
    }
```