# how to manage window elements from another window in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt

I have two Windows: MainWindow and Progress.

I can't set the state of progressBar from MainWindow, which is located in Progress.

I tried to do it like this:

> ***mainwindow.cpp***

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "progress.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
    ui->setupUi(this); }

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
    delete ui; }

void MainWindow::encode_file()  {
    Progress progress;
    progress.setModal(true);
    progress.exec();
    ui_progress->progressBar->setValue(0);}      // error: 'Progress' in namespace 'Ui' does not name a type
```

> ***mainwindow.h***

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "progress.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE namespace Ui { class MainWindow; } QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
   
    void encode_file();   private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Ui::Progress *ui_progress; };
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

> ***progress.cpp***

```
#include "progress.h"
#include "ui_progress.h"

Progress::Progress(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui_progress(new Ui::Progress) {
    ui_progress->setupUi(this); }

Progress::~Progress() {
    delete ui_progress; }
```

> ***progress.h***

```
#ifndef PROGRESS_H
#define PROGRESS_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui { class Progress; }

class Progress : public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Progress(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Progress();

private:
    Ui::Progress *ui_progress; };

#endif // PROGRESS_H
```

> ***main.cpp***

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec(); }
```

Comment: The closest thing to a duplicate that I found: [Defining a class within a namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623903/defining-a-class-within-a-namespace/)

Comment: I'm even more confused ...
The definition of Ui::Progress *ui_progress I have in mainwindow.h and in progress.h.

Comment: The call progress.exec() is blocking. Try progress.show()

Answer (score 0):

In short, your `progress.h` file is messed up. You added unnecessary complications that broke your code.

Presumably, you want to define `class Progress` in the `Ui` namespace, since you *declared* that class there. However, **you ended the namespace before the definition**. Here is your code with some comments added:

> ```
> namespace Ui { class Progress; }  // <-- This line has three parts.
> // ^^^^^^^^^^^ ------------------------- This part opens namespace Ui.
> //             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---------- This part declares that there is a
> //                                       class named Progress in that namespace.
> //                             ^-------- This part closes that namespace.
>
> class Progress : public QDialog { // <-- No namespace is open, so this starts a
>                                   //     definition of a class named Progress in
>                                   //     the global namespace.
>     /* class definition skipped */
> };
> ```

At this point, the compiler is aware of *two* classes named `Progress`, one in the `Ui` namespace, and one in the global namespace. The former is declared, while the latter is defined. The two are distinct, independent entities. After all, the reason we have namespaces in the first place is to allow the same name to be used for different purposes when placed in different namespaces. The compiler is fine with you stating that there are two classes named `Progress` since they reside in different namespaces. It is fine with the lack of a forward declaration of `::Progress` (global namespace). It is not happy about the lack of a definition of `Ui::Progress`.

If you want your definition of `Progress` to match your declaration, then don't end the namespace prematurely.

```
namespace Ui { class Progress;    // <-- No closing brace; the namespace remains open.

class Progress : public QDialog { // <-- Now this is in the Ui namespace
    /* class definition skipped */
}; // end of class Progress

}                                 // <-- Closes the Ui namespace
```

At this point, the forward declaration of `Ui::Progress` serves no useful purpose. You can get rid of it.

```
namespace Ui {

class Progress : public QDialog { // <-- In the Ui namespace
    /* class definition skipped */
}; // end of class Progress

}// end namespace Ui
```

(Alternatively, you could leave the namespace how you had it and start the definition (not the declaration) with `class Ui:Progress` instead of `class Progress`. If you choose this route, you need to keep the forward declaration. Your code becomes quite a bit longer for no benefit, though.)

After you fix the header file, the corresponding source file needs the same sort of fix. The easier option is to wrap the entire file (minus the `#include` lines) in your desired namespace. (The more involved option is to add the `Ui::` prefix to the start of the qualified function names.)

```
#include "progress.h"
#include "ui_progress.h"

namespace Ui {                    // Open the namespace

Progress::Progress(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui_progress(new Ui::Progress) {
    ui_progress->setupUi(this); }

Progress::~Progress() {
    delete ui_progress; }

}                                 // Close the namespace
```

**Summary:**
Declaring that there is a class with a certain name in namespace `Ui` does not mean that every class with that name is in namespace `Ui`. The definition must either also be in the namespace or be qualified as being in the namespace by using the `Ui::` prefix.

Comment: Brain explosion occurred.... My version of the code was originally created by QtCreator by default. I did as you said and still the error appears: no member named 'setupUi' in 'Ui::Progress'

Comment: I also noticed that method progress.show() doesn't work for some reason. Only progress.exec() works, but it blocks further execution.